# Community bot can send messages now?

Tags: support, comment, community-user

[image]

Today I saw this this comment by the [community bot profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).. has MSE community bot achieved artificial intelligence?

[post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235174/find-a-closed-expression-for-sum-i-0n-i5-without-using-faulhabers-for)

Comment: Can you add a link to the post in question?

Comment: That's no doubt a canned comment based on a flag or a vote to close. It seems to be a recent change.

Comment: Just jokes @InanimateBeing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a new feature for the first-post queues (as mentioned in a comment there are now two such queues, one for answers one for questions).

> Reviewers are encouraged to leave comments for the post-author, but now they can also choose from a few options of canned feedback which will appear as a comment from the Community account.

See [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release)

Comment: The First Post queue is now retired.  We now have First Question queue and First answer queue.  The community comment is a feature of the two new queues, not a feature of the now retired First Post queue.

Comment: Canned feedback. Just what we need. Bozhe moi.

Comment: "a few options"... I think there are but two. In First Questions, if you are not willing to Okay the question "as-is", and if you cannot find something to Edit, then the only way to finish/submit the Review is to post one of the two canned bits.

Comment: Can #1 contains "*Question is unclear.*
Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking."

Comment: Can #2 contains "*Question is too broad*
Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer."